# adsense making ip report all wrong with resubmittion page and generating random ips

Tags: javascript, php, ip, adsense, page-refresh

I have a google ad on my website, but I just found out today, that it's resubmitting the page with a random IP, that changes from time to time, mostly when submitting a form. It happens too, but rarely, when you refresh the page.

You see how this can be a problem, as it makes the IP report extremely wrong, as you don't know when the random IP that adsense generates changes. So if you only get around 20 actual IPs, the report might say around 100, because of adsense. Is there any way around this, for anyone else who uses adsense?

Sorry if my code is a bit long:

```
<script async src='//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js'></script>
<!-- ad3 -->
<ins class='adsbygoogle'
style='display:inline-block;width:50%;height:10%'
data-ad-client='ca-pub-2820065049351531'
data-ad-slot='4286171604'>
</ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>

<?php

include('connectX.php');

if (!$_SESSION['_ip_']) {
$_SESSION['_ip_'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$_SESSION['_proxy_'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} //end of if (!$_SESSION['_ip_'])

$ip = $_SESSION['_ip_'];
$proxy = $_SESSION['_proxy_'];
$page = clean($_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]);
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$date =  date('Y-m-d');
$time = date('H:i:s');

//*************************************************END OF IPCOUNT
$views = gd1("select views from ipCount where date = '$date' limit 1");

if ($views == null) {
id("insert into ipCount values('','0','0','$date')");
} //end of if ($views == null)
else {
$views++;
ud("update ipCount set views = '$views' where date = '$date'");
} //end of else not if ($views == null)
//*************************************************END OF IPCOUNT

//*************************************************START OF IPALL
$views = gd1("select views from ipAll where ip = '$ip' and date = '$date' limit 1");

if ($views == null) {
id("insert into ipAll values('','$ip','$proxy','1','$date','$time','0')");
$ipCount = gd1("select ipCount from ipCount where date = '$date' limit 1");
$ipCount++;
ud("update ipCount set ipCount = '$ipCount' where date = '$date'");
} //end of if ($views == null)
else {
$views++;
ud("update ipAll set time = '$time', views = '$views' where ip = '$ip' and date = '$date'");
}
//*************************************************END OF IPALL

//*************************************************START OF IP
$views = gd1("select views from ip where ip = '$ip' and page = '$page' and date = '$date' limit 1");

if ($views == null) {
id("insert into ip values('','$ip','$proxy','$page','1','$date','$time')");
} //end of if ($views == null)
else {
$views++;
ud("update ip set time = '$time',views = '$views' where ip = '$ip' and page = '$page' and date = '$date'");
} //end of else
//*************************************************END OF IP

$value = $_GET['hidden'];
$value++;

echo "
<form method = 'GET'>
<input type = 'submit' value = 'click'>
<input type = 'hidden' name = 'hidden' value = '$value'>
</form>
";

?>
```